# Yet Another Linker Error

Tags: c++, linker-errors, sfml

After an entire day of reinstalling different version of CodeBlocks, MinGW, and SFML, I finally got a good match. I used the tutorial main.cpp from the SFML website to test. Unfortunately, as soon as I tried to use Texture::loadFromFile(), I got this error.

```
||=== Build: Debug in SFML TEST (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\C++\SFML TEST\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_4RectIiEE'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

This is the command that the compiler uses:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\SFML-2.3.2\lib -o "bin\Debug\SFML TEST.exe" obj\Debug\main.o  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -std=c++11  -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d -mwindows obj\Debug\main.o
```

I've been searching the Internet far and wide, and it seems there are a million different people with a million different problems. Who ACTUALLY has it working??
Anyways, the error is the same whether I choose to do static/dynamic. I rechecked 4 times whether I linked incorrectly in the build options, but everything is there.

I have SFML 2.3.2, CodeBlocks 13.12, and MingW 4.2.0 gcc 5.3.0
Thanks for your time.

Comment: It might be helpful if you post the command that produces this error.

Answer (score 0):

The downloadable libs from SFML offer only compatibility to MinGW gcc 4.9.2, not to 5.3.0 you're using. Consider building SFML yourself by generating a workspace or makefile using cmake or consider using a compatible compiler version.
You're also linking both the release and debug libraries at the same time. One type is enough.

Comment: Changing from MinGW gcc 4.9.2 to 5.3.0 is what got SFML working, but I'll try reverting. The command is put together by the compiler, so I don't know why it would do that by default. Regarding: "using a compatible compiler version", 
Shouldn't the latest release of CodeBlocks (13.12) be compatible?

Comment: CodeBlocks itself has nothing to do with compatibility to SFML. Only the provided compiler does. And since SFML offers 4.9.2 and 5.3.0 is a major version increase, I doubt it. I still think your best solution is to simply use cmake (there's also a nice gui-version for it) to generate a workspace or makefile, build sfml yourself and be done with any kind of configuration errors. That's the way I do it ever since and it always works fluidly, no matter what compiler, ide or versions you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was hoping to avoid delving into cmake at all, but I guess I'll have to bite the bullet. Much appreciated, cheers.

Comment: It's really not a big deal at all. There's even a tutorial: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/compile-with-cmake.php

Comment: Do you have a link for MinGW 4.9.2, I can't seem to find it anywhere. The installer on sourceforge doesnt have anything above 4.8.1-4. I found a build of 4.9.2 in the filetree of that installer, yet there was no download button for it alone.